# Writing a SQL Query

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables:

product_description( name , **product_id**)

product( quantity, stock_status_id, price, **product_id**)

What I am trying to do is run a query that will get me the above data but I am not sure how to implement a join to get the joined data from both tables.

**Resolved**

I did the following:

```
SELECT product_description.name, product.quantity,product.price
FROM product
INNER JOIN product_description
ON product.product_id=product_description.product_id
ORDER BY product_description.name
```

Comment: Is there an `id` column in your `Product Description` table that matches an ID in the `Product` table?  If not, you're SOL.

Comment: Can you include the full table schemas?

Comment: I have updated the question for rockerest rests answer

Comment: the description of the tables isn't enough to formulate a query from.  run DESC Product, and DESC `Product Description' and edit your answer with the output.  Incidentally, spaces in table names is not considered "nice" and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Are those the full table schemas?  Product (the table) doesn't have an ID in it?  This is a simple query to write, given that we are provided the exact table definitions.

Comment: @AI W - name is the field name.

Comment: @chad they both have the same id column "product_id"

Comment: In that case, use an INNER JOIN as shown in several answers below.  None of them appear to be exactly correct based sorely on assumptions about your table definition.  See this link for more info:  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: I edited your question, it's better to show the schema of your tables like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operating under the assumption that you have matching `product_id`s in each table, here's a query that will return the data you need using implicit joins:

```
SELECT product.product_id, name, quantity, stock_status_id, price
FROM product, product_description
WHERE product.product_id = product_description.product_id
```

## UPDATE:

This works as I would expect.  Here are two table dumps that might help you, and the output of the query.

product table:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `product`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `product`
--

INSERT INTO `product` (`product_id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Croissant'),
(2, 'Danish');
```

product_description table:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `product_description`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_description` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stock_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` double NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `product_description`
--

INSERT INTO `product_description` (`product_id`, `quantity`, `stock_status_id`, `price`) VALUES
(1, 6, 2, 12.5),
(2, 13, 1, 19.25);
```

Output from the above query:

```
"1","Croissant","6","2","12.5"
"2","Danish","13","1","19.25"
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this?

```
select p.id, p.quantity, p.stock_status_id, p.price, d.name
from Product p inner join `Product Description` d on d.product_id=p.id
```

although I'm still not sure of what the table schema actually looks like from the description in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   -- name each column you want here
   -- prefix columns from the PRODUCT table with its alias like so:
   p.product_id,

   -- prefix columns from the other table as its alias
   d.quantity
FROM
    PRODUCT p  -- name of your PRODUCT table aliased as p
INNER JOIN     -- join against your other table
    PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION d -- name of your other table aliased as d
ON
    p.product_id = d.product_id -- match the foreign keys
```

See [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) documentation for more details.

NOTE:  This won't work as-is, you'll need to provide the columns that you want from each table in the `SELECT` clause, and probably fix the table names to match for your application.

Comment: I have adjusted my question again,  Will continue reading link